# Subtraction of days on DateObjects in JavaScript is not working (as expected)

Tags: javascript, date

Can someone please tell me why the console logs
untilDate Mon Mar 14 2022 here when it should log untilDate Thu Dec 14 2021

```js
let _untilDate = new Date(); // Mon Mar 14 2022
let _fromDate = new Date(); // Mon Mar 14 2022

_fromDate.setDate(_untilDate.getDate() - 89);
///_fromDate should now be Wed Dec 15 2021
_untilDate.setDate(_fromDate.getDate() - 1);
///_untilDate should now be Thu Dec 14 2021
console.log(`untilDate: ${_untilDate.toDateString()}`);
//actually logs untilDate Mon Mar 14 2022
console.log(`fromDate: ${_fromDate.toDateString()}`);
```

Comment: `_fromDate` is indeed the 15th of December. But `getDate()` give you `15`. `15 - 1` is `14`. That doesn't mean 14th of December if you never change the month.

Comment: Because you subtract 89 days from *_fromDate*, then log *_untilDate* that you only subtracted 1 day from. Edited to also print *_fromDate*.

Comment: Yes you are right, what a silly mistake.